# How is a "Generally Inactive" ham determined for Field Day GOTA?

Tags: contest, arrl, field-day

[ARRL Field Day Rules](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Field-Day/2013/2013%20Rules.pdf) allow a GOTA station to be operated by "a generally inactive licensee. " There are members of my club which started to become active again after a long term of inactivity a few months before Field Day. Are they allowed to use the GOTA station, citing general inactivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the 2013 Field Day rules, this is answered in the FAQ in the [information packet](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Field-Day/2013/2013-FD-Packet-V3.pdf). Emphasis is in the original document.

> Q. What is considered a generally inactive licensee?
>
> A. The GOTA station is not for everyone. The generally inactive licensee provisions pertain to someone who holds an amateur that 
>   has been inactive for a significant period of time. The intent and the spirit of this station is to provide an opportunity for persons to 
>   gain on-the-air experience and progress to operating the regular club stations in the future. The intent is not to develop a group of 
>   “permanent GOTA Field Day operators”. This is also not a station that a club “ringer” operates in order to rack up points. ***The list 
>   of operators of this station must be submitted with the Field Day entry.***
>
> In order to claim the GOTA bonus, the club/group must provide a list of operators and the number of QSOs each operator makes at 
>   the GOTA station. ***Clubs should use their best judgment in determining the operators of the GOTA station.***